# How can I attach an UI Builder/ Toolkit based wrist UI/ virtual smart watch to the wrist in XR?

Tags: unity-ui, oculus

I have a Unity project based on https://developer.oculus.com/documentation/unity/ using Unity 2021.3.23f1 .

The OVRPlugin is set to OpenXR.

In XR Plugin-In Management Oculus is selected.

The [Interaction SDK](https://developer.oculus.com/documentation/unity/unity-isdk-getting-started/) and [Meta Avatar SDK](https://developer.oculus.com/documentation/unity/meta-avatars-overview/) is added per guidelines.

https://developer.oculus.com/documentation/unity/unity-isdk-create-ui/ describes how to set up an UI, but neither it is [UI Toolkit/ Builder](https://html) based, nor attached to the wrist.

Does someone know of an example how to attach an UI (or whatever else) to the wrist?

The examples I found where all based on the generic XR solutions of Unity, but not the SDKs of Meta.